# How to use Facebook API to publish an event on a page after logging-in a user?

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I used the graph api in order to connect the user and publish an event on its wall.

But if I am connected as a page, I get this error message : "You need to be connected as a user and not as a page to run this app"

But I which I could publish my event on a fan page.

Here is my [TOKEN_URL](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CID&redirect_uri=RURL&client_secret=KEY&code=AUTH_CODE)

How shoud I do to be able to publish on my fan page.
How can I enable that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically add an event to a page using Graph API?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4925705/how-to-programmatically-add-an-event-to-a-page-using-graph-api)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To publish "on behalf" of a Page, you need to use a Page access token. To get a Page access token, first get an access token for a user with the `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT&scope=manage_pages,publish_stream&type=user_agent
```

Then, using the access token you get as a result, do a GET of:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_STEP_1
```

Here, you'll find the list of the Pages the user is an admin of. Here you can grab the access token for one of these Pages. Now calls you make will be made on behalf of the Page. Now anything you try to post will be posted as the Page. If you are trying to create events, you may also need the `create_event` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

To see how this works, you can test this out using these URLs in your browser or in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an offline access token with the manage_pages permission for the user that created/owns the fan page. After obtaining the user's access token, then you need to get the page's access token.
See this answer with code for details:
[How can I use 'manage_pages' permission with the SDK on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331086/how-can-i-use-manage-pages-permission-with-the-sdk-on-facebook/6740575#6740575)

Answer (score 0):

You could log in as the administrator of the page and create an **[offline access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602073/access-public-graph-api-resources-with-app-facebook/6602207#6602207)** for that user.