# How can I let my friends post on my facebook page wall, from my website?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Okay this question is very simple: I have a facebook page, and a website. People can post things on the facebook page wall (obviously) and I would like to put a button on my website that lets them post (messages or pictures) to my facebook wall.

Edit: I tried using the comment box and it doesn't let users post directly to my facebook page wall (which is what I want).

Edit: I'm currently investigating a deprecated facebook functionality using [post object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Any ideas ? Anything, even remotely connected to how I can do this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify a little bit, I wanted to use a "post" button on my facebook page that lets any users post directly to my facebook page wall, using my facebook app. Here's what you need to do if you want to do this

1) Get permission for the app to publish on their behalf. For this, the users need to be redirected to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=<your-api-key>&
cancel_url=<your-cancel-url>&display=popup&
fbconnect=1&next=<your-success-url>&
return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&req_perms=email%2Cpublish_stream
```

2) After you initialize the Facebook Javascript SDK, use the following function:

```
FB.api('/mypage/feed', 'post', { body: 'the body', message: 'some-text' }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response);
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Facebook introduced [Facebook comment box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/).

Comment: Right, I actually heard about that before...seems like a very nice resource. But does the comment box also let users put posts on the page ? Or is it just for commenting on already existing posts ?

Comment: In fact, I tried using the comment box and it doesn't let users post directly to my facebook page wall, which is what I wanted...

Comment: you are right, that's not what you exactly want, i wrote it in edit. I think, if you want to do that, u'll have to do some work with FB API. I have no completed solution this time.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bit of a risky operation; the comments box (suggested by loler) is the safest as this is contained.

But if you must go ahead, you should be able to do it. Warning - not advising it unless you otherwise moderate the posts - and it might be against terms and conditions to let others post to your wall, so check first!

1. Create yourself an "app"
2. Log into your own app, make the token a long lived token and store that token.
3. (Remember to perviodically extend your token to prevent it running out after 60 days).

Then, separately:

1. Create a PHP form (or other page) that accepts details to be posted to Facebook
2. Then post using your saved token (and with your app credentials) using the Graph API through PHP.

Do not do this via Javascript as you need your access token, and you don't want to reveal that to the world.

Comment: That sounds like a really neat solution, but in this case wouldn't the backend php post as the page, rather than the user ?

Comment: That's why you log in as the user (separately) and store the access token - that access token allows a PHP script (with the same app credentials) post to that user's wall as that user. It will reveal the app name that the post was made with, but that's unavoidable (AFAIK). I should make it clear that "logging in as the user and storing the token" is a completely separate operation from the PHP form. Update: answer edited to make the separation clear.

Comment: Right, but this wouldn't be applicable if I wanted to have ANY page fan post as him/herself on my page wall, would it? I should've been a little clearer in the question sorry about that ...

Comment: Yep - you should have probably said that ;).. Will this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331086/how-can-i-use-manage-pages-permission-with-the-sdk-on-facebook

Comment: Yes and no... I think the best way to go is still to just use the opengraph and curl into facebook to post things...